# Best way to issue regular payouts to many wallets?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm trying to create a contract that will dish out regular inflation to all holders of the token. Every x period, it needs to scan the addresses and calculate their inflation, minting new tokens and adding it to their total.

What is the most cost efficient way to do this? Is it cheapest to iterate over the map and update each address, or better to calculate all values in memory and replace the map? Perhaps there is a better way I'm not thinking of.

Not sure how big the map could get, but cost efficiency is key here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cheapest way to do this is to have a smart contract function that allows a wallet holder to "claim" their inflation payment. e.g. instead of iterating over every address, you let the wallet holders to do the inflation calculation just for their address.

The cost to you is 0, just have to ensure the smart contract logic is correct

Comment: When you say the cost is zero, are you excluding the cost of gas to update their new value?

Comment: Well, I don't know exactly how you are calculating the inflation payment. If the logic is known in advance (e.g. if you hold for 100k blocks you get 1% bonus) then you can just code it in the contract. If the logic is triggered from outside entry, (e.g. every time some event happens, people who qualify get 1% bonus) then you can do it as a single contract method call

Comment: If, however, your inflation payment uses individual logic for every account, then you would need to call a method for every individual, and then yes, you spend a lot of gas :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! The idea is to be a percentage of token held, given out weekly. so either via API or internally in the contract, I want to trigger a function that calculates everyone's inflation at once.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to regularly send token/eth to account addresses I urge you to read up on the [withdrawal pattern](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.20/common-patterns.html?highlight=withdrawal%20pattern#withdrawal-from-contracts). If you do not follow the withdrawal pattern, a malicious party can set up a smart contract that will get your transaction stuck during the payout.

Instead of sending funds directly you create a map about how much each address is allowed to withdraw. This is very similar to the map about which address holds how many token.

When transferring out of your contract now, only the transaction of the withdrawing party is affected.